# Updating a table in MS Access based upon Column Names

Tags: ms-access

I have inherited a MS Access project that is way beyond me: Table A has exam data, so each field in A is the name of an exam item and the value is the points earned on that item. My task is to convert those results to Table B, which has one field for the item name and one field for the corresponding value.

So it looks like this:

```
Table A:
  A.Item01
  A.Item02
  etc.

Table B:
   NameofFieldinTableA
   Result
```

...so if A.Item01 = 1, I'd like that to update to Table B as:

NameOfFieldinTableA = Item01
   Result = 1

My apologies for not being able to better explain this, but this has got me completely stumped. My only guess is to write something in VBA?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'd use VBA to loop through the fields in your table - using the NAME property to get the NameofFieldinTableA and the VALUE property to get the Result.  So the VBA would look something like this:

```
Dim rsA as dao.recordset
Dim rsB as dao.recordset
dim fld as dao.field

Set rsA = CurrentDB.openRecordset("TableA", dbopendynaset)
Set rsB = CurrentDB.openRecordset("TableB", dbopendynaset)

Do Until rsA.EOF
   For each fld in rsA.Fields
       rsB.AddNew
       rsB!NameofFieldinTableA = fld.Name
       rsB!Result = fld.Value
       rsB.Update
   Next
   rsA.MoveNext
Loop

rsA.close
rsB.Close

Set rsA = Nothing
Set rsB = Nothing
```