# Updating a table in MS Access based upon Column Names with Unique Identifier

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm following up on a project that I [asked about earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288678/updating-a-table-in-ms-access-based-upon-column-names), where I have two tables: Table A contains exam results from an external source, which I want to update into Table B. Such as:

```
TableA:
UniqueIdentifier
Item01
Item02
etc...

TableB:
UniqueIdentifier
NameofIteminTableA
Result
```

So if the first record in TableA is UniqueIdenifier = 10, Item01 = 1, and Item02 = 3, then I'm trying to put that into TableB as as two records: First record would be uniqueIdentifier = 10, NameofIteminTableA = Item01, and Result = 1. Second record in TableB would be uniqueIdentifier = 10, NameofIteminTableA = Item02, and Result = 3.

This code is really close:

```
Dim rsA as dao.recordset
Dim rsB as dao.recordset
dim fld as dao.field

Set rsA = CurrentDB.openRecordset("TableA", dbopendynaset)
Set rsB = CurrentDB.openRecordset("TableB", dbopendynaset)

Do Until rsA.EOF
   For each fld in rsA.Fields
       rsB.AddNew
       rsB!NameofFieldinTableA = fld.Name
       rsB!Result = fld.Value
       rsB.Update
   Next
   rsA.MoveNext
Loop

rsA.close
rsB.Close

Set rsA = Nothing
Set rsB = Nothing
```

But I got that code from [mbizup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6730379/mbizup) before I realized that I need to have the uniqueidentifier field.

Sorry if I'm not explaining this well, but any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you run the code? what are you getting? any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim rsA as dao.recordset
Dim rsB as dao.recordset
dim fld as dao.field

Set rsA = CurrentDB.openRecordset("TableA", dbopendynaset)
Set rsB = CurrentDB.openRecordset("TableB", dbopendynaset)

Do Until rsA.EOF
   For each fld in rsA.Fields
       If fld.Name <> "UniqueIdentifier" Then
           rsB.AddNew
           rsB!UniqueIdentifier = rsA!UniqueIdentifier '<<<<<<<<
           rsB!NameofFieldinTableA = fld.Name
           rsB!Result = fld.Value
           rsB.Update
       End If
   Next
   rsA.MoveNext
Loop

rsA.close
rsB.Close

Set rsA = Nothing
Set rsB = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim Williams---that worked exactly like I needed it to!